# ggplot: plot colors along axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot my data along x-axis for a picture like this:

[image: Colors along x axis]

My dummy data looks like this:

```
From  To  Class
1     3   a
4     5   b
6     10  c
10    12  b
```

Explanation: On X-axis there are intervals; Each interval has specific class. How to plot (map) those intervals on x-axis and assign colors according class (eg., `a=red,b=blue,c=green`)?

Comment: What happens between 3 and 4 and between 5 and 6?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, there is no connection between them. They are just different occurrences.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'd rather ask why the third and fourth row overlap, since it makes more sense to represent the ranges with discrete and not continuous values.

Comment: @Pgibas, why did you delete your question regarding converting numbers to letters? I was just posting a nice solution when you've deleted it...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thank you for the help, but I found out that such problem can be solved (not always) with one command `chartr`.

Comment: @Pgibas, did you succeed to replace all `1:26` numbers with `a:z` using `chartr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `geom_rect`.

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- read.table(text="From  To  Class
1     3   a
4     5   b
6     10  c
10    12  b", header=TRUE)

ggplot(DF, aes(xmin=From, xmax=To, ymin=0, ymax=1, colour=Class, fill=Class)) + 
  geom_rect() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

First bring your data in the according form:

```
require( plyr )
dt <- adply( dt, 1, function(foo){
  data.frame( x = seq( foo$from, foo$to ), Class = foo$Class )
})
```

Then plot with a tile geometry removing all theme elements:

```
ggplot( dt, aes(x = x, fill = Class, y = 1 ) ) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    line = element_blank(),
    text = element_blank(),
    line = element_blank(),
    title = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides( fill=FALSE)
```

[image]